# What are the enforcement mechanisms of the ECHR and possible consequences of ignoring the ruling?

Tags: bosnia-and-herzegovina, echr

Citizens concerned about issues with the constitution of Bosnia & Herzegovina have won 5 cases at the European Court of Human Rights between December 2009 and December 2020 (see my website- https://input.sh/human-rights-vs-constitution-of-bosnia-herzegovina/).

The basic issue is that the constitution defines three "constitutent people groups" (Bosniac, Serb, Croat) and only allows people that identify as members of one of them to run for the upper house of the parliament (House of Peoples) or the presidency. Five separate cases were won based on two articles of the Dayton agreement (AKA the constitution) that define those two roles.

Considering that:

- B&H is a ratified member of the Council of Europe,
- That, according to Wikipedia, member states are obliged to execute the decisions,
- It's been over a decade since the first verdict was reached (December 2009),
- There's no real push for the constitution to be replaced or amended

...are there any real consequences that might pressure the country into complying? Wikipedia does nothing to describe enforcement mechanisms of the ECHR nor possible consequences, and I don't know where to look. In other words, what might happen next?

Answer (score 1):

If we're going to talk about the concrete cases connected here, the first of which was [Sejdic and Finci](https://www.coe.int/en/web/execution/-/exchange-with-eu-on-execution-of-echr-judgments-by-bosnia-herzegovina) (2009), the EU has been (gently?) pressuring Bosnia & Herzegovina to adopt the constitutional changes that would satisfy the ECHR judgement(s) on this matter, basically by conditioning the beginning of EU membership talks on this (among 14 conditions).

Apparently, this case-series is the only instance in which ECHR found the constitution of a country to be in violation of the Convention. Alas, as in most countries, changing the constitution can be an involved process. The ECHR (or CoE) does not have any way to force countries to apply its decisions. In this case, the political wing of CoE, its [Committee of Ministers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Committee_of_Ministers_of_the_Council_of_Europe) did [set up a group](https://hudoc.exec.coe.int/eng#%7B%22EXECIdentifier%22:%5B%22004-3141%22%5D%7D) that regularly examines the matter, in terms of (lack of) progress. Presumably, no greater pressure was deemed necessary. The [Parliamentary Assembly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parliamentary_Assembly_of_the_Council_of_Europe#Sanctions_against_the_Russian_delegation) did for instance sanction Russia in the past (for the Ukraine events), but as with all things CoE, the effects/powers were limited to suspending the participation of the Russian delegation.

Of some (related) note here, Russia [also has](https://www.juridicainternational.eu/index.php?id=15646#_ftnref3) a long backlog of ECHR decisions not implemented (over a thousand at one point) and "it takes, on average, 9.7 years to implement a judgment of the ECtHR in Russia", even though no constitutional impediments exist in Russia's cases, as far as I know, although:

> the tensions between the ECtHR and Russia reached their peak when, in December 2015, Russia adopted a law (‘The Amended Law on the Constitutional Court’) refusing to acknowledge the binding force of the ECtHR’s judgments and empowering the Constitutional Court of the Russian Federation to declare said judgments unenforceable when implementation would be in conflict with the Constitution of Russia

On this point, you'll want more generally to read on the [*lex posterior* issue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monism_and_dualism_in_international_law) of the application of international law (decisions).