# What's currently preventing the seizure of Russian assets to satisfy the Yukos court judgement?

Tags: russian-federation, international-law, echr

According [to Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yukos_shareholders_v._Russia):

> The Yukos Oil Company's former shareholders and management filed a series of claims in courts and before arbitration panels in various countries, seeking compensation for their expropriation. The largest, for over $100 billion, was filed at the international Permanent Court of Arbitration in The Hague in 2007 and resulted in the arbitrators awarding Yukos majority shareholders over US$50 billion in damages. This decision was appealed by Russia and overturned by the Hague's district court, before being upheld by the Court of Appeal of the Hague.

It seems like [recent court cases](https://archive.is/wzH3W) have confirmed that the ECHR judgement is legitimate but actual seizures [have been unsuccessful](https://www.reuters.com/article/netherlands-russia-yukos/dutch-court-says-seizure-of-vodka-assets-by-yukos-shareholders-was-illegal-idUSL1N2HI17K) so far. What's currently preventing the seizures of Russian governments assets? Is it purely due to the lack of political will or is there an expected date on which those seizures will start taking place?

Comment: IIRC, Russia does not automatically transpose ECHR judgements into national ones. And it can take years for the latter to happen. And sometimes the national courts just snub ECHR. I think there was a related Q here about that. https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/61396/18373

Comment: @Fizz I don’t expect Russia to actually pay up but their EU assets should in theory be up for grabs and those assets are not tiny

Comment: probably the fact that EU would still wish do business with RU, and that it is a somewhat extraterritorial affair, which means a seizure could make other trade partners (especially in the murky world of nationalized energy companies) want to reduce the vulnerability of placing their financial assets in EU banks.